# Saving CSV output from Azure function to Azure container (Python 3X)

Tags: python-3.x, azure, csv, azure-functions, azure-blob-storage

I want to run an Azure function and save a CSV output to a Azure container.
I currently have two blocks of code that

1. Generates a CSV file.
2. Loads a CSV file into my container.

Each blocks works on my local PC in a Jupyter Notebook.

But I am struggling to combine them to work together in an Azure function. So I am looking for help.

Block 1 (Generate the CSV)

```
import yfinance as yf
import pandas as pd
from datetime import date
import csv

#stock names
NZX =[["Ascension Capital Limited", "ACE"],["AFC Group Holdings Limited", "AFC"],["Z Energy Limited", "ZEL"]]

today = str(date.today().isoformat())
directory = "C:\\Users\\Etc...\\SharePrices\\CSVs\\"  

df_list = list()
for i in NZX:
    code =i[1]
    name =i[0]
    cmpy =  f"{code}.NZ"
    tickerStrings = [cmpy]
    for ticker in tickerStrings:
        data = yf.download(ticker, group_by="Ticker", period='1d')
        data['ticker'] = ticker  
        df_list.append(data)       
df = pd.concat(df_list)
df.to_csv(f"{directory}_{today}.csv")
```

Block 2

```
from azure.storage.blob import BlobClient

blob = BlobClient.from_connection_string(conn_str="Myconnectionstring", container_name="container1", blob_name="StevesBlob3.csv")
with open("./output.csv", "rb") as data:
    blob.upload_blob(data)
```

Can anyone point me in the right direction? Current issues I am struggling with

1. Do I need to save the file in a temp folder in the Azure function before trying to move it, or can I push it directly to the container
2. How do I reference the destination folder/container when I save the CSV?

Any guidance would be much appreciated.
New to Azure functions.

Comment: 1) you can upload from memory string to blob storage. 2) Please explain what question 2 means - ***How do I reference ...*** 3) If the file is small you can create an API endpoint (REST) and call the Container Instance endpoint located in your app from the Azure function. There is no need for Azure Storage (unless the object is large or you want to decouple data transfer).

Comment: From memory sounds attractive. The the other questions. 1)  "How do I reference" - I mean the equivalent of "./output.csv" (which references the current working directory in the current code),  but In my case I want to reference / write to  the  container destination.    2) Re the file size. Perhaps a few MB- the production code will extract  200 companies daily share prices over 5 years, with perhaps10 columns of data. The data is ultimately being loaded into Power BI for reporting and Analytics. CSV is easy for Power BI. An API data is less easy (additional parsing in Power BI etc.) .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Example with a generated CSV file

```
#creates random csv in blob storage
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime

from azure.storage.blob import ContainerClient

#Create dynamic filename
dateTimeObj = datetime.now()
timestampStr = dateTimeObj.strftime("%d%b%Y%H%M%S")
filename =f"{timestampStr}.csv"

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(5, 3), columns=['Column1','Column2','Colum3'])
df.to_csv(filename, index=False)  

blob = BlobClient.from_connection_string(
    conn_str="DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=storageaccountXXXXXXX;AccountKey=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX;EndpointSuffix=core.windows.net",
    container_name="container2",
    blob_name=filename)

with open(filename, "rb") as data:
    blob.upload_blob(data)
```